# Generate a Short EmailConfirmationToken

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement a registration prozess for my webapp. The problem is that the generated "`userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);`" code is to long. Is there any possibility for generating a short one like this: "qwert12345asdfg6"

My UserTokenProvider is implemented like this:

```
        var dataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("IdentityServer3");

        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")) 
            {
                TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
            };
        }
```

Do you have an idea what do I need to do?

Comment: Why is it too long? Are you not just appening it to a url that gets passed around (e.g. via email)?

Comment: Sure, but I want to generate a short code which do not have 200 signs is that possible and if yes whoch can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Identity uses the `UserTokenProvider` of the `UserManager` to generate and validate the token.

You can implement your own `IUserTokenProvider<TUser, TKey>` or extend the the default one than set that as UserManager.UserTokenProvider.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24994413/659695