# ASP.NET MVC Identity - how to change format of generated Token in SMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

Using the two factor authentification in ASP.NET MVC / Identity, I successfully set up the UserManager.SmsService.

By default, ASP.NET Identity generates a 6 digit long verification token which is sent by SMS. However, our requirement is to have a 4 characters long alphanumeric token instead.

The code is generated with this command:

```
var code = await UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), phoneNumber);
```

Is there a way to define the format of the generated code?

Comment: Looking at the source code for ASP.NET identity 2.3 (current RTM), the number of digits is hardcoded (see like 35/36 of https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.3.0-rtm-150806/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs). So it't not possible except by overwriting the complete mechanism which might have impact on other features as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994115/custom-email-confirmation-token) SO answer for details.

Basically you have to create a class inheriting `IUserTokenProvider<TUser, TKey>` and implement those two methods: `GenerateAsync` and `ValidateAsync`.

There you will write the code to generate and validate your six characther token. The same token will be used everywhere inside the ASP.NET Identity without any other code change.