# Custom Verification Code/Token in Asp .Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I need to create short code (6 digits) for Email Confirmation using Asp.Net Identity.
Currently, if I use

```
"GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync"
```

it provides me with very long code instead of this I want to generate a code which is only 6 digit in length. 
Is there any way to achieve this how can I extend identity to provide such a feature. any leads towards this will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994115/custom-email-confirmation-token) SO answer for details.

Basically you have to create a class inheriting `IUserTokenProvider<TUser, TKey>` and implement those two methods: `GenerateAsync` and `ValidateAsync`.

There you will write the code to generate and validate your six characther token. The same token will be used everywhere inside the ASP.NET Identity without any other code change.

Comment: Thanks, I did this implementation using EmailTokenProvider